# Динамический массив статических массивов

Tags: c++

Статический массив динамический массивов я могу объявить так

```
int* arr[LENGHT];
```

Как объявить динамический массив статических массивов?

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите! Статический массив - это постоянная, неизменная область память, доступ к которой возможен на протяжении всей работы с программой. Статическую переменную нельзя объявлять динамически. В этом и есть особенность!

Comment: У меня есть статические массивы объявленные обычным образом: `int arr[LENGHT]`. Я лишь хочу собрать указатели на них в одном динамическом массиве.

Comment: Ну так соберите. Хотя проще всего инициализировать массивом-константой, который в программе уже будет, так что заводить ещё динамический массив -- лишняя морока. И, кстати, что такое динамический массив (желательно ссылку на место в стандарте языка)?
А то я часто тут вижу "динамический массив", а что это такое -- не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, то, что Вы хотите получить, - это не массив массивов, а массив указателей на другие массивы. Делается так же, как и изначальный вариант:

```
int a1 [20];
int a2 [30];
int a3 [15];

int** arr = new int* [3];
arr[0] = a1;
arr[1] = a2;
arr[2] = a3;
```

Comment: Только вот

     int *arr[] = {a1, a2, a3};

гораздо естественней.

Comment: Так требуется же динамический массив (т.е. по меньшей мере делаемый в куче)

Comment: А вот тут и всплывает интереснейший вопрос -- нафига?

Comment: А это уже вопрос к автору вопроса )))

Answer (score 3):

Гм. Если я правильно понимаю, традиционно в C++ для «динамических массивов» используют `vector` из STL.

Напрямую, `std::vector<int[LENGTH]>` сделать нельзя, получите ошибку. Но можно сделать структуру-обертку:

```
struct WrappedArray { int value[LENGTH]; };
std::vector<WrappedArray> arrays;
```

Или использовать `std::tr1::array`:

```
typedef std::tr1::array<int, LENGTH> my_subarray;
std::vector<my_subarray> arrays;
```

Или держать указатели (добро пожаловать в управление памятью):

```
std::vector<int(*)[LENGTH]> arrays;
```

Вроде бы как-то так, надеюсь, не ошибся (кресты помню смутно). Плюсоводы, если что — ругните, поправьте плз.